# Replace some column values in PostgreSQL function returning SETOF tablename

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a base table with many derived tables in PostgreSQL 9.2. For each derived table there is a function that returns "SETOF *derived_table*". These functions are generated code and they don't need to know the derived column names, because they simply call

```
SELECT *
FROM derived_table
WHERE [some conditions on base columns]
```

I now want the functions to modify the returned values for some of the base columns, but continue to return all the derived columns, ie. something like this:

```
SELECT 'something else' AS base_col1, base_col2, base_col3, [all derived columns]
FROM derived_table
WHERE ...
```

Is there a way to express this in Postgres without listing all derived column names?

Alternatively, I could return the data I want in separate columns if only there was a way to define the function to return something like "SETOF my_special_column+derived_table". Again, I want to somehow avoid listing all the derived column names, so the functions can still be easily auto-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a view of the modified columns

```
create view view_derived_table as
select 'something else' as new_column, *
from derived_table;
```

Then you can return a `setof` `view_derived_table`

```
create function f_view_derived_table()
returns setof view_derived_table as $$
    select *
    from view_derived_table
    where some_condition;
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: An interesting idea! As posted, this still requires me to manually list the derived columns, but if I add a new column instead the view can be defined as:
`SELECT 'something else' AS new_column, * FROM derived_table`

Comment: @EM Yes, that is what I was my intention but I just copied your code and forgot to change it to `, *`